# Parsing JSON data with recyclerview and volley error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am trying to fetch JSON data from mySQL to android app, following [this](https://uniqueandrocode.com/display-data-from-mysql-database-in-android-using-volley/). I am getting this error `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`. I tried look up other posts suggestion but still can't solve the problem. Below are the codes I am working on:

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String HI ="http://xxx/phpMyAdmin-5.0.4/Appi.php" ;   //xxx is ip and the user name
    private List<List_Data> list_data;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        list_data=new ArrayList<>();
        adapter=new MyAdapter(list_data);

        getMovieData();

    }

    private void getMovieData() {
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, HI, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                        JSONObject ob=array.getJSONObject(i);
                        List_Data listData=new List_Data(ob.getString("name")
                                ,ob.getString("moive"));
                        list_data.add(listData);
                    }
                    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

The JSON format is:

```
 [{"ID":"1","name":"ab","movie":"cd"},{"ID":"2","name":"ef","movie":"gh"}]
```

The adapter is:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private List<List_Data>list_data;

    public MyAdapter(List<List_Data> list_data) {
        this.list_data = list_data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_data,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        List_Data listData=list_data.get(position);
        holder.txtname.setText(listData.getName());
        holder.txtmovie.setText(listData.getMoviename());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return list_data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView txtname,txtmovie;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            txtmovie=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_moviename);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I setup the class like so:

```
    public class List_Data {
    private String name;
    private String moviename;

    public List_Data(String name, String moviename) {
        this.name = name;
        this.moviename = moviename;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getMoviename() {
        return moviename;
    }
}
```

And the activity_main.xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And lis_data.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:textColor="#111"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="name:"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                android:textColor="#111"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:textColor="#111"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="moivename:"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_moviename"
                android:textColor="#111"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

Comment: It is always good option to run in debug mode with checkpoints on every function so that you can get where the app reaches or else put log statements in functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, adapter will always re-set when new data obtained. It is better to set the adapter once and notify data change whenever new data obtained.
Here my suggestion.
on onCreate set recycler view adapter

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    list_data=new ArrayList<>();
    adapter=new MyAdapter(list_data);
    // set adapter
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    getMovieData();

}
```

in `getMovieData()` after data updated, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of set new adapter

```
private void getMovieData() {
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, HI, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                    JSONObject ob=array.getJSONObject(i);
                    List_Data listData=new List_Data(ob.getString("name")
                            ,ob.getString("moive"));
                    list_data.add(listData);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This seems help fixing the `E/RecyclerView:` problem but the data is still not display on emulator.. do you have any idea for why that might happen? I follow the same step as the tutorial..

Comment: please make sure function `onResponse` called (and not error), also list_data is not empty when `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` called

Comment: The app is running with out error popping. So I think passing through `onResponse`. I tried debugged this line `adapter=new MyAdapter(list_data);` and it says `adapter: null list_data: size =0;` Does that mean its empty and do you have suggestion what to do? Sorry for asking you that many question here I am a bit newbie for android...

Comment: it is okay if initial list_data is empty. as long as when new data added to `list_data` you call `notifyDataSetChanged`. please try to `print` list data size before called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in onResponse. for example by adding code `println(list_data.size)` and check in logcat, is it empty or not

Comment: I try ` println(list_data.toString())` and it has nothing to pop out:( I also tried to reach you by email:( ...

Comment: hi @swiftlearneer sorry. Just to make sure, do not forget to add internet permission in you `AndroidManifes.xml` file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: All good! Yes! I have that on `AndroidManifes.xml`... but the app is running but still no output of the JSON

Comment: make sure the json data is `{ "data":  [{"ID":"1","name":"ab","movie":"cd"},{"ID":"2","name":"ef","movie":"gh"}] }` instead of just `[{"ID":"1","name":"ab","movie":"cd"},{"ID":"2","name":"ef","movie":"gh"}]` like in your question above

Comment: Hi, hakim! Thanks for the response! Maybe that's a dump question.. Do you have direction on making "data" in front of the ID? I access the php and it showed as what I had.

Comment: Because I don't know how you implemented it in your server side (php), I can't help about it. But, you also can modify your android code when parse json, instead of create json object from string, you can create jsonarray directly. remove this code `JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);` and modify `JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");` to `JSONArray array=new JSONArray(response);`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! Basically I just read out the MySQL table using phpMyadmin.. I gave it a try (your suggestion) and after some digging and it still a blink page on the android emulator even though the app running fine....

Comment: I did get warnings as I checked the Logcat : `W/fetchingtestin: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)` and `W/fetchingtestin: Verification of void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.<init>`

Comment: Could I also contact you for further discussion if you have time:((

Comment: I also found that `new Response.Listener<String>()` is greyed out in `StringRequest stringRequest`. Do you have an idea why its that?. I updated blow

Comment: Do have time to take a look at my new post?

Answer (score 0):

Updates: I tried @hakim's suggestion. The app is still running but the data is not display.

I also found that `new Response.Listener<String>()` and `new Response.ErrorListener()` is greyed out in the getMoiveData() in the following:

```
private void getMovieData() {
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, HI, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray array=new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                    JSONObject ob=array.getJSONObject(i);
                    List_Data listData=new List_Data(ob.getString("name")
                            ,ob.getString("moive"));
                    list_data.add(listData);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used below code

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String HI ="http://xxx/phpMyAdmin-5.0.4/Appi.php" ;   //xxx 
       is ip and the user name
    private List<List_Data> list_data;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        list_data=new ArrayList<>();
     
        getMovieData();

    }

    private void getMovieData() {
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, HI, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                        JSONObject ob=array.getJSONObject(i);
                        List_Data listData=new List_Data(ob.getString("name")
                                ,ob.getString("moive"));
                        list_data.add(listData);
                    }
                       setAdapter(listData)
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

     public void setAdapter(List<List_Data> list_data){

  adapter=new MyAdapter(list_data);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    

   }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried but the app still running fine (no errors) but the its a blank page with no MySQL data shown.....